# I'm struggling with importing modules correctly

Tags: python, import

I am very new to programming and Python is my first language. I am currently trying to make a program that would tell me if items in a list are shared. I have these lists saved in a dictionary(titled `my_dict`) on another file. I do not want these lists and dictionaries in my code if I don't have to and I thought importing would solve my issue. I created two files.
the first is saved as `Users/myname/Documents/Programming/my_file.py`
the other is saved as `Users/myname/Documents/Programming/my_dict.py`

In `my_file` I wold like to import the dictionary and use it in my function. I tried:

```
import my_dict
print my_dict
```

the error I got was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_name/Downloads/my_file.py", line 9, in <module>
    import my_dict
ImportError: No module named my_dict
```

Please help me understand why this importing does not work.

Comment: Point the working directory with `from os import chdir chdir("/Users/myname/Documents/Programming/my_dict.py")` to the one, where your script is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your files are in Users/myname/Documents/Programming folder. However, the error message is complaining about a different folder - Users/myname/Downloads folder.

Check your paths and make sure the files are in the correct folders.

Comment: Sure enough. Thanks for the help!